# How to ("geometrically") differentiate unit vectors of spherical coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vectors, differentiation

I have been trying to derive the expressions of partial derivatives of unit vectors with respect to each other in the spherical coordinate system. I was able to get all of them except $\frac{\partial \hat{\phi}}{\partial\theta}$

Note: I am using the mathematics convention of denoting azimuthal angle as $\phi$ and polar angle as $\theta$

Here's the figure I've made but I'm not able to find the angle of interest marked with a question mark in the figure.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The drawing in my initial figure is wrong. The figure attached below is the correct one and it saliently provides the answer.
[image]
The angle of our interest is $\angle BAC$ named $\alpha$. To find this,
$$ \tan{\phi}=\frac{AB}{OB}=\frac{AB}{r}$$
$$ AB=r\tan{\phi} $$
Now,
$$ \tan{\alpha}=\frac{BC}{AB}$$
From the figure it is clear that $BC=r\sin{\phi}d\theta$ and we found that $AB=r\tan{\phi}$. Substituting,
$$ \tan{\alpha}=\frac{r\sin{\phi}\;d\theta}{r\tan{\phi}}=\cos{\phi}\;d\theta$$

Hence the magnitude of change in the unit vector $ \hat{\theta}$ is $1\cdot\alpha=\tan{\alpha}=\cos{\phi}\;d\theta\;$ for small angles. From the figure it is clear that the direction is $\hat{\theta}$. Putting all of this together,
$$ \frac{\partial\hat{\phi}}{\partial\theta}=\cos{\phi}\;\hat{\theta}$$

Comment: In your question you say you need $\partial\hat\theta/\partial\phi$, but in this answer you find $\partial\hat\phi/\partial\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My apologies, it was a mistake on my part getting muddled up in the physics vs. math conventions about spherical coordinates. I have reflected the change in the question.